# How to use a DelegatingFilterProxy in AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-java-config

I want to register a DelegatingFilterProxy in the onStartup method of a AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer. Unfortunately, the delegate bean for the DelegatingFilterProxy has not been created when the servlet gets initialized:

```java
@Order(1)
public class MvcWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic localeFilter = servletContext.addFilter("localeFilter", new DelegatingFilterProxy("localeFilter"));
        localeFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
    }
    ...
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    ...
    @Bean
    public LocaleFilter localeFilter() {
        return new LocaleFilter();
    }
    ...
}
```

How can you make sure the the localeFilter bean gets created before the servlet's startup?

Comment: You don't nor shouldn't you do it this way. Just override the `getServletFilters`. The filter should be loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` and not the `DispatcherServlet` as the `DelegatingFilterProxy` is only able to access beans in the root context (the one loaded by the `COntextLoaderListener`).

Comment: I know that the getServletFilters method exists, but I could not find out how to add a url pattern mapping for the filters.

Comment: Defining the filter bean in the root context works. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: You don't define a pattern mapping because those filters will automatically be bound to the `DispatcherServlet` (as also explained in the javadoc of the class/method).